# ckeditor load html code in the editor asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

I am trying to load html file in CKEditor in asp.net but for some reason I don't know how to put the html code from the code behind file.

```
CKEditor1.FilebrowserBrowseUrl = url;
CKEditor1.BasePath = url;
CKEditor1.Text = content;
```

none of that helped
Any advice? Thanks in advance, Laziale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which version you are using, but let's suppose that it's 3.x. I was playing around with the control and didn't find any possible way of doing this from code behind. However, I managed to make it work like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "fckInitialization", @" 
        window.onload = function () {              
                var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances['" + txtPost.ClientID + @"'];
                oEditor.insertHtml('<strong>This is a bold text.</strong>');                
        };
        ", true);
```

I tried it in IE 8 and the last version of Mozilla (I think it was 9) and it worked. I also tried the same thing, but instead of **window.onload** I used the jQuery **$(document).ready()** and it worked only in IE. The reason is that you have to wait for everything to load in order to use the functions from the CKEditor API. I played with Firebug and the **insertHTML** worked.
If you are using 2.x, you can see somewhere in Google the same approach, but with a different API. I just can't find the link right now.

Another problem will be here, as you may figure out, that if you want to initialize a long text, you will have to write everything in a script, which is not really nice.

Maybe a possible solution for you will be to convert the HTML to BBCode first and then just set the **Text** property. This, of course, depends on the way you use the control, because BBCode does not contain all possible tags, but you can always modify the bbcode plugin of CKEditor to meet your needs. And I tested it and it works.

PS. Probably you can do it with the JavaScript method and an AJAX call.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ckeditor is being initialized from a textarea field, you can simply populate the body of the textarea.

Comment: thx for your reply, but I have this only: <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1"  runat="server">
</CKEditor:CKEditorControl>. Do I need to use textarea as well?

Comment: No, in this case you are using a wrapping around CKEditor. Setting the TEXT property of the CKEditorControl does not work?

Comment: nope, it gives me the html code as text, not rendered as html in the control, and I have the startup mode to WYSIWYG

Comment: @Laziale You should do Html.Raw(youHtmlString)